# Updating graph based on input range

Tags: javascript, html

This forum always provided quick and good comments on different coding problems.
Today I want your help! Please!

I have a project in HTML and I want to add some features. I have to create a graph based on a function `(f(x_r))`. This function will depend on two parameters, x1 and x2.

I want that these 2 parameters to be from the input range (`E_sursa` and `r_intern`).
I've tried different methods, but I was not able to make for example `x1` or `x2` a parameter or a constant (from the function `citire`). I also try some old methods presented in this forum, but they did not work.

Sorry some words from the code are in Romanian.

The goal:
"var x1=1; var x2=1;" to update their values based on (E_sursa and r_intern or ) 
x1 from the function citire to be used in the first sript (this one with var x1=1;)

**Edit**
how could i replace var x1; with the value from var 
'x1 = document.getElementById("r_sursa").value;'
I try to read it as a parameter ( to call a function), but it did not worked: 
'function Resis() { return document.getElementById("r_sursa").value;} var x1=Resis();'

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>  
<script>
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    zoomEnabled: true,
    title:{
        text: "power" 
    },
    axisY :{
        includeZero:false
    },
    data: data  // random generator below
});
chart.render();

}

var limit = 100;
var x1=1;
var x2=1;
var y = 0;
var data = [];
var dataSeries = { type: "line" };
var dataPoints = [];
for (var i = 0; i < limit; i += 1) 
{ x_r = i/10;
    y = x2*x2*x_r/((parseFloat(x1)+x_r)*(parseFloat(x1)+x_r));
    dataPoints.push({
        x: x_r,
        y: y                
    });
}
dataSeries.dataPoints = dataPoints;
data.push(dataSeries);               

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script></head>
<body>

<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 50%;">
</div>

<label for="r_sursa">resistance</label>
 <input type="range" id="r_sursa" name="r_sursa" min="0" max="10" step="0.1">
<b id="demo1"></b>
<br>
<label for="E_sursa">voltage</label>
 <input type="range" id="E_sursa" name="E_sursa" min="0" max="12" step="0.1">
<b id="demo2"></b>
<br>
<label for="R_sarcina">ohms</label>
 <input type="range" id="R_sarcina" name="R_sarcina" min="0" max="10" step="0.1">
<b id="demo3"></b>
<br>
amps
<b id="demo4"></b>
<br>
power
<b id="demo5"></b>
<br>
<script>
function citire() {
var x1 = document.getElementById("r_sursa").value;
var x2 = document.getElementById("E_sursa").value;
var x3 = document.getElementById("R_sarcina").value;
var curent, putere;
y=parseFloat(x1)+parseFloat(x3);
curent = x2/(parseFloat(x1)+parseFloat(x3));
 putere = x2*x2*x3/((parseFloat(x1)+parseFloat(x3))*(parseFloat(x1)+parseFloat(x3)));
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x1 + " &#x3A9;";
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = x2 + " V";
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = x3  + " &#x3A9;";
 document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = curent.toFixed(2)+ " A";

 document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML = putere.toFixed(2)+ " W";
}
setInterval(function() { citire(); },0);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Your question contains some formatting issues which may make it very difficult for people to understand the problem you are presenting. Could you attempt to edit the question to better explain what it is you're having trouble with? I would recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which offers several tips to this end.

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can check it again and see if it match your intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reassign the `data` attribute of the `chart` object and then invoke the `render()` method every time you have a new dataset.

For your needs of assigning `x1` to the slider's value right at the load time, you can easily figure it yourself by reading my sample code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <script>
      var limit = 100;
      var chart;

      function getData() {
        var x1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("r_sursa").value);
        var x2 = 1;
        var y = 0;
        var data = [];
        var dataSeries = {
          type: "line"
        };
        var dataPoints = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < limit; i += 1) {
          x_r = i / 10;
          y = x2 * x2 * x_r / ((parseFloat(x1) + x_r) * (parseFloat(x1) + x_r));
          dataPoints.push({
            x: x_r,
            y: y
          });
        }
        dataSeries.dataPoints = dataPoints;
        data.push(dataSeries);
        return data
      }

      window.onload = function() {

        chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
          animationEnabled: true,
          zoomEnabled: true,
          title: {
            text: "power"
          },
          axisY: {
            includeZero: false
          },
          data: getData() // random generator below
        });

        chart.render();
      }

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 50%;">
    </div>

    <label for="r_sursa">resistance</label>
    <input type="range" id="r_sursa" name="r_sursa" min="0" max="10" step="0.1">
    <b id="demo1"></b>
    <br>
    <label for="E_sursa">voltage</label>
    <input type="range" id="E_sursa" name="E_sursa" min="0" max="12" step="0.1">
    <b id="demo2"></b>
    <br>
    <label for="R_sarcina">ohms</label>
    <input type="range" id="R_sarcina" name="R_sarcina" min="0" max="10" step="0.1">
    <b id="demo3"></b>
    <br>
    amps
    <b id="demo4"></b>
    <br>
    power
    <b id="demo5"></b>
    <br>
    <script>
      function citire() {
        var x1 = document.getElementById("r_sursa").value;
        var x2 = document.getElementById("E_sursa").value;
        var x3 = document.getElementById("R_sarcina").value;
        var curent, putere;
        y = parseFloat(x1) + parseFloat(x3);
        curent = x2 / (parseFloat(x1) + parseFloat(x3));
        putere = x2 * x2 * x3 / ((parseFloat(x1) + parseFloat(x3)) * (parseFloat(x1) + parseFloat(x3)));
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x1 + " &#x3A9;";
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = x2 + " V";
        document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = x3 + " &#x3A9;";
        document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = curent.toFixed(2) + " A";

        document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML = putere.toFixed(2) + " W";
        
        chart.options.data = getData();
        chart.render()
      }
      setInterval(function() {
        citire();
      }, 0);

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```